# Doctrine Querybuilder, LEFT JOIN on unidirectional OneToMany and ManyToMany relation

Tags: doctrine-orm, count

I use doctrine 2.5 and I struggle doing a multiple-count request with the queryBuilder.

#### MDD

[image: MDD]
As you see, the AbstractArticle entity have a ManyToOne relationship with Tag nammed `mainTag` and a ManyToMany relationship with the same entityTag nammed `tags`.

#### What I want to do

I want to make a request, from a list of tag Ids, to count the number of AbstractArticle main tagged AND AbstractArticle default tagged.

Here the kind of return I want

```
+--------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| TagId  | mainTaggedArticleCount  | defaultTaggedArticleCount  |
+--------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
|      1 |                       2 |                          0 |
|      2 |                       0 |                          5 |
|      3 |                       2 |                          2 |
+--------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
```

#### My current attempts

I did it successfully with the following mySQL request and I got exactly what I want :

```
SELECT 
tag.id as tagId,
(select count(DISTINCT aaMain.id)) as mainTaggedArticleCount,
(select count(DISTINCT aaDefault.id)) as defaultTaggedArticleCount

FROM tag tag
/* Left join on ManyToOne nammed `mainTag` */
LEFT JOIN abstract_article aaMain ON aaMain.main_tag_id = tag.id
/* Left join on ManyToMany nammed `tags` with the junction table */
LEFT JOIN abstract_article_tag aat ON aat.tag_id = tag.id
LEFT JOIN abstract_article aaDefault ON aaDefault.id = aat.abstract_article_id

where tag.id in (3, 1, 5, 6) /* My list of tag Ids */
group by tag.id
```

But with doctrine is far more complicated ><... I did the leftjoin for the OneToMany relationship like this :

```
$qb->leftJoin(AbstractArticle::class,'mainTaggedArticle',Join::WITH,'mainTaggedArticle.mainTag = t.id')
```

But it doesn't work for the ManyToMany. Because the junction table `abstract_article_tag` is invisible throught doctrine.

Any ideas for me ?
Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it ! 
With 2 subrequests, here my solution

Inside my TagRepository

```
$repoAbastractArticle = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository("AbstractArticle");

// SubRequest for main tagged article
$countMainTaggedArticleSubQuery = $repoAbstractArticle->createQueryBuilder("abstract_article");
$countMainTaggedArticleSubQuery->select('COUNT(DISTINCT abstract_article.id)')
    ->leftJoin('abstract_article.mainTag', 'mainTag')
    ->andWhere($countMainTaggedArticleSubQuery->expr()->eq('mainTag.id', 'tag.id'));

// SubRequest for tagged article 
$countDefaultTaggedAbstractArticleSubQuery = $repoAbstractArticle->createQueryBuilder("default_tagged_abstract_article");
$countDefaultTaggedAbstractArticleSubQuery->select('COUNT(DISTINCT default_tagged_abstract_article.id)')
    ->leftJoin('default_tagged_abstract_article.tags', 'tags')
    ->andWhere($countDefaultTaggedAbstractArticleSubQuery->expr()->eq('tags.id', 'tag.id'));

// Main request
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("tag");
    $qb->select('
    tag.id AS tagId, 
    (' . $countMainTaggedArticleSubQuery . ') AS mainTaggedArticleCount, 
    (' . $countDefaultTaggedAbstractArticleSubQuery . ') AS defaultTaggedArticleCount'
    )
    ->groupBy('tag.id')
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('tag.id', ':tagIds'))
    ->setParameter('tagIds', $tagIds);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```